# How to pass event listener to the root component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue3 and I know that when working with components you can pass listener callbacks using **v-on** directive or use its shorthand **@** (like in the example below).

```
<my component @click="myCallback"/>
```

But is there a way to pass them to the app (root component)?

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
// import the root component App from a single-file component.
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'

const app = createApp(MyComponent, {props})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-on-*` template syntax is translated to `on*` props in [`h` function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#creating-vnodes), which is used to create vnodes. Considering that `MyComponent` emits `foo` event, it's:

```
const app = createApp(MyComponent, { onFoo() {...} })
```

Comment: I guess your answer is too complex for this case. :-)

Comment: Depends on what the OP wants, which is unknown. If the intention is to communicate with root comp in entry point in some way then that's how it's done

Comment: Apologies for the poor construction of the question. That is exactly what I was looking for. I will edit it, so others can understand. Thank you @EstusFlask!

Comment: @EstusFlask Ok, you won. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing callbacks to the components, but reacting to events from them. If you want to react on some event in the Vue `root app`, then just define `v-on`s in the root template.

So, for your example:

If you put your component into the app template and define the callback as app  method, then your method will be called when the event occurs.

App

```
<template>
    <my component @click="myCallback"/>
</template>
```

and

```
methods: {
    myCallback(event) {
    ....
    }
}
```

Example

```js
const MyComp = {
  emits: ['click'],
  template: `<button id="my-button" @click="$emit('click', $event)">Click me!</button>`
}

const App = {
 components: { MyComp },
 methods: {
    myCallback(event){
        alert('Clicked button: ' + event.target.id)
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <my-comp @click="myCallback"></my-comp> 
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```